# Error run tensorflow lite example

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I try to build and run tensorflow lite example(minimal).

Build is ok, but error occurs running this program.

why this error occur?

Used model is custom model training on tensorflow and convert tensorflow lite using toco.

```
root@90f212114f89:/tensorflow# bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/minimal/minimal /root/DNNSE/model/tflite_model.lite
tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/reduce.cc:107 current >= 0 && current < input_num_dims was not true.
tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/reduce.cc:107 current >= 0 && current < input_num_dims was not true.
tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/reduce.cc:107 current >= 0 && current < input_num_dims was not true.
tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/reduce.cc:107 current >= 0 && current < input_num_dims was not true.
Node 8 failed to prepare.

Error at tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/minimal/minimal.cc:59
```

Node 8 failed to prepare. <- this error throw in interpreter PrepareOpsStartingAt() function.

I think some error in model converting .tflite

How can i debugging this issue?

I used build option this below.

```
 bazel build ... --compilation_mode=dbg -s
```

Any another useful build option?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please provide some more detail? Which specific TensorFlow code is causing this issue?

Comment: @jkdev tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/example/minimal <- I try to build this code and run. code is not modified.
This error occurs minimal.cc (59 line). That is allocate tensor buffers

Comment: It seems there is something incorrect in the shapes of your output graph. Can you try updating your TF version and see if the error still occurs?